# ¿ Como deshabilitar validacion de formulario en elementos dentro de un fieldset o div?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Tengo un formulario dividido en zonas con div o fieldset y necesito que cuando el div o fieldset este oculto al hacer el submit no me valide los elementos de input, select, checkbox, ... con algun atributo de validación como required, max, min, pattern, etc … que haya dentro.

```
<form>
  <div id="pregunta1">
      <input type="text" required />
      <input type="date" required />
  </div>
  <!-- Los elementos dentro de div=pregunta2 no deberian validarse -->
  <div id="pregunta2" style="display:none">
      <input type="number" required />
      <input type="email" required />
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: usas Jquery o Js puro?

Comment: solo JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola mi propuesta es que quites los required de los input que estan ocultos inicialmente, despues acompañes lo que tienes con una funcion de js que haga el div visible y a su vez tambien ponga los otros campos required... Finalmete quedaria algo asi, puse un boton para ejecutar la funcion pero puedes ejecutarla desde donde quieras:

```js
function mostrar(){
    
  //Mostramos la pregunta2 
  document.getElementById('pregunta2').style.display = 'block'; 
  
  //pasamos el atributo required a los campos
  document.getElementById("campo1").required = true;
  document.getElementById("campo2").required = true;
       
    
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div id="pregunta1">
      <input type="text" required />
      <input type="date" required />
  </div>
  <!-- Los elementos dentro de div=pregunta2 no deberian validarse -->
  <div id="pregunta2" style="display:none">
      <input id="campo1" type="number"/>
      <input id="campo2" type="email"/>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>

<button type="submit" onclick="mostrar()">Mostrar pregunta 2</button>
```

Comment: No me sirve ya que además de required, puede tener pattern , max, maxlength, etc...

Comment: Eso no impide hacer lo que comenta @jhon-arteaga. El resto de atributos (max, pattern, etc.) pueden seguir estando.

Comment: Si dejo los atributos de validacion como max, pattern, etc... al hacer el submit me saldra un mensaje como con required y esto es lo que quiero deshabilitar

Comment: No debería... Acabo de modificar mi respuesta con un `pattern` y una vez quitado el `required` no valida nada más.

Comment: Efectivamente lo he vuelto a probar y tienes razón para que valide tiene que tener el required asi que el pattern no influye.

Answer (score 2):

Otra opción alternativa a la de @jhon-arteaga es dejar los `required` inicialmente y antes de hacer el `submit` deshabilites los `inputs` en función de si su div padre esta visible o no.

```js
function requiredFalse(){  
  let divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');  
  for(let i = 0;i < divs.length; i++) {  
      if(divs[i].style.display == 'none') {
       let inputs = divs[i].children;
       for(let i = 0;i<inputs.length; i++) {
          inputs[i].required = false;
          alert(inputs[i].id + " deshabilitado!");
       }
   }
  }
}

function showDiv(){
  document.getElementById('pregunta2').style.display = 'block';     
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div id="pregunta1">
      <input type="text" required />
      <input type="date" required />
  </div>
  <!-- Los elementos dentro de div=pregunta2 no deberian validarse -->
  <div id="pregunta2" style="display:none">
      <input id="campo1" type="number" required pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}"/>
      <input id="campo2" type="email" required/>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" onclick="requiredFalse()">Enviar</button>
</form>

<button onclick="showDiv()">Mostrar div pregunta2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay otra opción que es deshabilitando los inputs con el atributo "disabled" o substituyendo el "div" por un "fieldset" y agregándole un "disabled". Entonces el código quedaría tal como:

```
<form>
  <fieldset id="pregunta1">
     <input type="text" required />
     <input type="date" required />
  </fieldset>
  <!-- Los elementos dentro de fieldset=pregunta2 no deberian validarse -->
  <fieldset id="pregunta2" style="display:none" disabled>
    <input type="number" required />
    <input type="email" required />
  </fieldset>
 <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```